# A quadratic nonresidue of the form $x^2+1$

Tags: number-theory

Given a prime $p=4k+1$ does there exist an integer $x$ such that $$\left(\frac{x^2+1}{p}\right)=-1?$$

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  If nothing else, it ought to be very easy to work several examples and thereby decide if the claim appears to be true or not.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I am too lazy.

Comment: @lulu Hi. (+1) Do you know,   what does this mean? $\left(\frac{x^2+1}{p}\right)=-1$

Comment: @lonestudent That's the Legendre symbol, it means that $x^2+1$ is not a square modulo $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of the residues modulo $p$ can be quadratic, so if you start from $1=1^2$ and count up, the first *nonquadratic* one you meet must have this form.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.